I can't zoom out with InteractiveViewer, Column and Row in Flutter
I have something like this:
InteractiveViewer(
                boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                minScale: 0.5,
                maxScale: 3.0,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        width: 1000,
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );

I never used this widget before and I'm trying to replicate a native behaviour so I could easily zoom in/out and scroll up/down. Like inspecting a photo on the phone.
Without any SingleChildScrollView I see the "overflowed" error. Not sure if that's really necessary. Right now I can only scroll up/down but I can't zoom out to see the whole thing

remove SingleChildScrollView and add constrained: false

that seems to do the trick. Create an answer and I'll accept it.
Also, do you know how to fix this? Inside the Column what I really have is this: GridView.count(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
crossAxisCount: totalGridWidth,
I can't provide a fixed size for the Grid

so you want to provide a fixed width for your grid? if so wrap it with SizedBox

I was just missing constrained: false

To replicate the native behavior of inspecting a photo on the phone, where you can zoom in and out and scroll in all directions, you can use the InteractiveViewer without the SingleChildScrollView. The InteractiveViewer itself supports panning and zooming.
In my opinion, you can do this like this:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Interactive Viewer Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            minScale: 0.1,
            maxScale: 3.0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 200,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 1000,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
You should be able to zoom in and out and scroll in all directions to view the entire content. The InteractiveViewer will handle the scaling and panning of its child widgets.

Also you can use expanded widget but it will do alot things to consider

that's not working. I can zoom in/out and the overflowed issue is in both lists

Try use the flexible widget where it causing overflow issue.
